# RichText rendering issue for anonymous users

Tags: websphere-portal, richtext, wcm

I am trying to render richtext content from WCM using wcm API. I have jsp to do so. It renders properly for all user group except anonymous. When I view rendered content I see broken image inside richtext. When I log in and view the rendered content, image is displayed.

here is my code:

```
Workspace ws = WCM_API.getRepository().getSystemWorkspace();
ws.login();
DocumentLibrary lib = ws.getDocumentLibrary("Portal Site");
String s1 = "";
String s2 = "";


if (lib!=null) {
    DocumentIdIterator<Document> it = ws.findByName(DocumentTypes.Content,"kino");

    if (it.hasNext()) {
        DocumentId<Document> docid = it.next();

        Content doc = (Content) ws.getById(docid);
        s1 = "Title: " + doc.getTitle() + "\n";

        RichTextComponent c = (RichTextComponent) doc.getComponent("Body");

        s2 = "Text: " + c.getRichText();
    }
} 
out.println(s1);
out.println(s2);
```

s2 is outputs richtext with image for authorized users.
When I logout and view s2 output: text is displayed but image is broken

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution has nothing to do with access level in my case!
I checked url of the content and in both cases it consisted /myconnect word (example: http:ip_address:port/wps/wcm/myconnect/...)
I found out that myconnect is for authorized user
and connect is for anon users. (example: http:ip_address:port/wps/wcm/connect/...)
Just by replacing myconnect with connect in the url to the wcm content I managed to solve the problem:

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you have anonymous access granted to all your RichText component and parent site areas at user level. 
And add this call on workspace object

```
workspace.useUserAccess(true);
```

Comment: I already tried useUserAccess(true) as well as useLiveAccess(true), but both don't seem to work in my case. But anyway thanks for advice

Comment: What about access permissions? Does your rich text has user access granted?

Comment: I could set Contributor access to anon user but it's not secure (won't be allowed to do so). But I tried on test server and it helps.

Comment: Check library permissions at Portal Administration -> Content Library as well, make sure anon users has access

Comment: You also can try get anonymous workspace for anon users and workspace by principal for logged in users.